# Google Maps "Sorry, we have no imagery" and 403 forbidden error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

At one of the companies I consult with, their application just started displaying "Sorry, we have no imagery" where the Google Map used to display.  It doesn't seem that we are bing blocked for reaching a limit of any sort, though I can't be 100% sure.  I did look and it seems they are not using an API key, however, if I add one in, nothing changes.

The application can be viewed here: http://devtp.airtreks.com/HtmlUi

Any help or direction on troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.  If you need any further details, please let me know.

Thank you,
Justin

[UPDATE]
It seems the issue might be related to location/access point.  I have attempted to access via my office, my home office, asked a buddy to look at it, my wife from her office, and a co-worker from their home. All are reporting the same.

[Here is a link to a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9epes8j04b97wz/tp_issue.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original answer was deleted, not sure why, but I'll give this a go. One possibility is that you're loading files both with http and https, and sometimes mixed content can cause these sorts of errors. Try loading the Maps API with https, which is permissible, or just // and see if that helps solve the issue.

Comment: Weird, the other answer has disappeared as well.  Maybe because I updated the question?  In any case, I don't believe we are loading anything from https, just http, however, I'll try changing it to // to see what happens.  I believe I tried that in one of my original attempts with no success, but can't remember.  I'll post an update after trying.  Thanks, Mano.

Comment: Okay, I'm not seeing anything from https except the facebook xml namespace. I attempted to change everything from google to https:// with no change.  I now everything from google set to //, no change.

Comment: Gonna mark this as the answer, though, I'm really not 100% sure what happened.  But, things seem to be working again.  Hopefully they will stay that way and the // was the fix.  Thanks for the responses and assistance!